# How to redirect a deleted page of Drupal 7 to a views page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, drupal

One of my sites has thousands of pages that are to be deleted due to their expiry, and redirected from the old paths to new pages created by views of Drupal 7. The site is using the clean url setting.

Example:

**From:** http://www.example.com/language/directory/page-path

**To:** http://www.example.com/views-page-path

I tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^/language/directory/$ /views-page-path [R=301,L]
```

but nothing happened.

Please advise how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with .htaccess as said before.

But if this happens a lot to you and if you want to manage your redirects, you can also install module Redirect 
https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect I'm already using. It is useful for redirecting individual URLs. Besides I achieve this using rules but no way to send header 301 (moved permanently). Drupal and Google webmaster tool logging them is error 404 (page not found). Though I prefer to use htaccess, a solution with rule is also welcome.

Comment: Panels & Page Manager can maybe help you too, you can setup a page to return HTTP header 301 for url patterns

Comment: Yes done it! Thanks for your valuable advise. I was not aware much about the power of page manager. I cancelled attempting through both htaccess and rule. It was a long journey to reach the things which was within my reach. Thanks and Regards once again.

Comment: In my experience with Drupal; you always have to look for hours to find how to perfom the 2min action you need. Glad to help ;p